# How to open&save a video file in python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, pygtk

I've just started to make a ubuntu application using PyGtk. My very first object is to open, convert and then save a video file. Ignoring convert phase, I'm going to implant open-save functions. But at the moment when I open a video file, and save it, I get non-video file with 11B size. I've just google this and found [OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html#intro) for python. But I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it. I also think I'm going to use ffmpeg libraries to do some manipulates on video files. Is it what I want or there might be other built-in libraries?

By the way, here's my code to open and save the file :

```
    def on_openFile_clicked(self, widget):
        filename=None
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        response = dialog.run()
        self.add_filters(dialog)

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            filename = dialog.get_filename()
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print 'Cancel Clicked'
        dialog.destroy()

        print "File Choosen: ", filename

    def add_filters(self, dialog):

        filter_py = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_py.set_name("Video Files")
        filter_py.add_mime_type("video/mp4")
        filter_py.add_mime_type("video/x-flv")
        dialog.add_filter(filter_py)

        filter_any = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_any.set_name("Any files")
        filter_any.add_pattern("*")
        dialog.add_filter(filter_any)

    def on_saveFile_clicked(self, widget):
        filename=None
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_SAVE, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        response = dialog.run()
        self.add_filters(dialog)

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            filename = dialog.get_filename()
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print 'Cancel Clicked'
        dialog.destroy()

        if filename != None:
            save_file=open(filename, 'w')
            save_file.write("Sample Data")
            save_file.close()
        print "File Saved: ", filename
```

Comment: How do you get 11KB of data from `.write("Sample Data")`? That's 11 bytes, not 11 kilobytes.

Comment: You're right. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I think **OpenCV** is the best way ! because of its diverse and powerful functions for processing media ! and also supports `Windows`, `Linux`, `Mac OS`, `iOS` and `Android`. OpenCV was designed for computational efficiency and with a strong focus on real-time applications. Written in optimized C/C++, the library can take advantage of multi-core processing . you can find many [Video Analysis](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/video.html#video-video-analysis) functions in OpenCV !